# function that checks the length of the cycle

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, cycle

Hey guys i have the function, but it gives me error when I test it. 
Does anyone have any Idea on how to fix it
This is my exercise. Please read through.

Write a function cycleLength(array), which returns the number of students that form a loop, given that you start by talking to the left-most one. The input array is a list of non-negative integers, such that array[m] is the number of the student to whom student m redirects. No student redirects to himself. The left-most student is number 0, the next is number 1, and so on. Each element in the list will be in the range [0, n-1] where n is the length of the list.
For example, suppose the list was [1, 3, 0, 1]. Then student 0 redirects to student 1, who redirects to student 3, who redirects back to student 1. There is a loop of two students: 1, 3. Thus the answer would be 2. Note that even though you started with student 0, he is not part of the loop.
Here is my function:

```
def cycleLength(m):
    lst = []
    i = 0
    while i not in lst:
        lst.append(i)
        i = int(m[i])

    b = len(lst) - lst.index(i)
    return b
```

Comment: What if there are multiple loops of multiple sizes?

Comment: You forgot the `i += 1` at the end of the loop ;)

Comment: What is the error? Please [edit] your question to include the **complete text** of the error or traceback in the question itself, not in the comments. Please also give example input, the expected output, and the actual output you are getting. We are not mind readers, you have to tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right.

```
>>> def cycleLength(students):
...     seen = []
...     current = 0
...     # Run till we have seen all the students
...     while len(seen) != len(students):
...         # If the current index has been seen already
...         if current in seen:
...             return len(seen) - seen.index(current)
...         seen.append(current)
...         current = students[current]
... 
>>> assert(cycleLength([1, 3, 0, 1]) == 2)
>>> assert(cycleLength([1, 3, 0, 2]) is None)
```

This will take care of the case where there is no loop as well.

Comment: Question, when i put a negative number it should return false. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Before `if current in seen`, you can simply do `if current < 0: return...`

Answer (score 1):

```
def cycleLength(m):
    lst = []
    for x in m:  
        if x in lst:
            return len(lst) - lst.index(x)
        lst.append(x)     

    return -1
```

**Explanation:**

1. you should loop while the element at index i `m[i]` is not already in `lst` - what you where doing is looking for the index in the list instead of "the element at index"
2. Same as previous point, you should append to `lst` the elements - not the index of the elements - otherwise you won't find any such "duplicate" elements - since the index *should* just increase.
3. Regards the last point - the index should keep increasing on each iteration
4. And last, the length of the cycle is between the first time that an element appears to the next time that you iterate the same element. And it's *not* necessarily from the beginning of the list.

**Correction:**

Previous version of the code had bugs, a simpler version of the same idea, and which is also bug-free (I believe), is posted here. -1 represents "no cycles found".